# Cannot launch Settings (gnome-control-center) on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, settings

My problem is to open System Settings on Ubuntu 19.10 but every time I click on settings, loading sign appears on status bar and disappear after about 10 seconds. And the worst is that I cannot access it everywhere even WiFi settings, Bluetooth settings, and everything about settings.

I've tried using the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

but, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I have the same problem as well...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I run this command, then it worked

> $ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

[image: apt-get install screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.6 /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.4
```

I personally found this error while upgrading (sudo eopkg upgrade) in Solus GNU/Linux version 1.2.1. The symptom was I could not launch GNOME Control Center, the GUI was not appearing. The source of problem was because GNOME Control Center asked for libwebp.so.4 but this file was gone and upgraded into libwebp.so.6 because of upgrading. So the solution was I just needed to create new "file" named libwebp.so.4 "linking" to the existing libwebp.so.6. The command above did this solution.

edit:
Tish may vary as per derivatives and versions. Cause now it works as this in pop s:

```
'sudo ln -svi /usr/lib/libpop_upgrade_gtk.so /usr/lib/libpop-upgrade-gtk-ffi.so.0'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The second link command worked for me. I installed pop-theme in Ubuntu 18.04 and got this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gnome-control-center is not able to load if any of key is not found. kindly run  below commands.

```
sudo rm -rfv /home/kali/.config/dconf
sudo apt install gnome-control-center --reinstall
```

now open settings.